# Error while building the Docker image: "chown: cannot access 'app/csv/': No such file or directory"

Tags: docker

I am trying to create a Docker image for a python application and getting the following error

```
=> ERROR [7/9] RUN chown -R myuser:mygrp app/csv/ resources/datafeed.id                                                                                                           0.4s
------                                                                                                                                                                                  
 > [7/9] RUN chown -R myuser:mygrp app/csv/ resources/datafeed.id:                                                                                                                      
#11 0.325 chown: cannot access 'app/csv/': No such file or directory
#11 0.325 chown: cannot access 'resources/datafeed.id': No such file or directory
------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c chown -R myuser:mygrp app/csv/ resources/datafeed.id]: exit code: 1
```

My Dockerfile is as follows :

```
FROM python:3.8-slim-buster

WORKDIR app/

COPY requirements.txt .

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

RUN groupadd -r -g 2000 mygrp && useradd -u 2000 -r -g mygrp myuser

RUN chown -R myuser:mygrp app/csv/ resources/datafeed.id

RUN chmod -R 700 app/csv/

COPY app .

USER myuser

CMD [ "python", "./main_async.py" ]
```

Also my project structure does have these files:

```
Project-folder/app/csv
Project-folder/resources/datafeed.id
```

Comment: Have those files been copied into the container yet? `RUN` runs a process inside the container so make sure that the files were copied into the container, and that the working directory of the `chown`  process is what you expect it to be (using `cd &&` is a common approach), or use absolute paths.

Comment: Your `COPY` step is _after_ the `RUN chown` step. You are `chown`-ing files before they have been `COPY`-ed into the container.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have your commands in the wrong order.

```
WORKDIR app/

...

RUN chown -R myuser:mygrp app/csv/ resources/datafeed.id
RUN chmod -R 700 app/csv/

COPY app .
```

The [`RUN <process>`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#run) command will run whatever `<process>` is *inside the container*. In your current Dockerfile, you are `chown`-ing files you haven't copied yet inside the container.

Do the `COPY` first.

Make sure you are passing the correct arguments to [`COPY`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy), which should generally be:

```
COPY <source on the host> <dest on the container>
```

So, if you are building from the `Project-folder` directory:

```
WORKDIR app

...

# Copy files from the host into the container.
# Since `WORKDIR` is already set, this copies
# all files in the current directory on
# host to under WORKDIR
COPY . .

RUN chown -R myuser:mygrp app/csv/ resources/datafeed.id
RUN chmod -R 700 app/csv/
```

Comment: Hi @GinoMempin that didnt help unfortunately. same error somehow.

Comment: @JainamShah From which folder are you running the docker build command? Is it from `Projecr-folder`? If so, then your COPY command is wrong, because it will only copy files from under app (on your local directory).